# Unable to remove family member from Googles' FamilyLink

Tags: google-play-services

I want to remove a member from the Family Group but there is no option available.
Hey Google, I Want to remove a member from the Family Group. But there is no option available. I dont want to delete the account because that is important.
any idea how to do it?